# Return view with activated filter in Odoo

Tags: filter, view, odoo

I'm trying to return a tree view in Odoo filtered by a parameter. Some one knows how to code the variable **my_context** of the view?
I need to apply the filter with the field: father_competence_id

The filter is defined as:

```xml
<filter name="groupby_fathercompetence"
    context="{'group_by' : 'father_competence_id'}"
    string="Father competence" />
```

```py
academic_record_lines = self.env['education.record']
for line in self:
            academic_record_lines = academic_record_lines + line.env['education.record'].search([('n_line_id', '=', line.id)])
return {
            'name': _('Academic records for {} [{}]').format(
                description, self.planification_id.teacher_id.name),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'education.record',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'context': **my_context**,
            'domain': [('id', 'in', academic_record_lines.ids)],
        }
```

Comment: Is there already a filter in the model's search view? If yes, how is its `name`?

Comment: @CZoellner yes it is, it's name is:      <filter name="groupby_fathercompetence"
      context="{'group_by' : 'father_competence_id'}"
      string="Father competence" />

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
my_context = dict(self._context or {})
my_context.update({'':})
```

Using  my_context.update you can add filters through context.

```
return {
        'name': _('Academic records for {} [{}]').format(
            description, self.planification_id.teacher_id.name),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'education.record',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context': my_context,
        'domain': [('id', 'in', academic_record_lines.ids)],
    }
```

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with:         my_context = dict(self._context or {})
        my_context.update({'group_by':'father_competence_id'}) , but the error still there.

Comment: Please use my_context.update({'search_default_groupby_fathercompetence':1}). You should written a groupby in search as below                                                                      <filter string="father competence" name="fathercompetence" context="{'group_by':'father_competence_id'}"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you know the filter name, which is normally set by attribute `name` on the search `<filter>` entries, you can automatically activate them by an action by providing the filter name with `search_default_` in front of it and as value a truthy value like `True` or `1`.

```py
academic_record_lines = self.env['education.record'].search(
    [('n_line_id', 'in', self.ids)])
context = dict(self.env.context or {})
context['search_default_groupby_fathercompetence'] = True
return {
    # self.pla... only working with singleton!!!
    'name': _('Academic records for {} [{}]').format(
        description, self.planification_id.teacher_id.name),
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'tree,form',
    'res_model': 'education.record',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'context': context,
    'domain': [('id', 'in', academic_record_lines.ids)],
}
```